# Is there any efficient function for extracting the probability vector after running pyspark ML algorithm other than rdd.extract in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I want to extract the probability from the vector and make it into rows. For that i have used `rdd.map(extract)`

```
def extract(row):
    return(row.prediction,)+tuple(row.probability.toArray() .tolist())
```

I have 96 probabilities within that vector. After extracting them into rows i sorted and selected top 10 probabilities. This works good for small dataset like 1000 records (ie. 96*1000 =96000 rows). But for 100k records the function is taking more time. So is there any other way to extract those probabilities and make them as rows?

Answer (score 0):

One thing might be improved in your code is to calculate the top-N directly in `extract()` function instead of retrieving all *96* probabilities and then post-processing them to find top-N. For example using [np.partition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) on the Numpy ndarray returned from `toArray()` method:

```
from numpy import partition, arange

N = 10

extract = lambda row: (row.prediction,) + tuple(-partition(-row.probability.toArray(),arange(N))[:N])

my_model.summary.predictions.rdd.map(extract).take(20)
```

**Note:** if order is not important for the top-N probabilities, then adjust `arange(N)` to `N`.

**EDIT:** Since Vector is not natively supported by SparkSQL(as of Spark 2.4.4), to use Dataframe APIs and its optimization, you'll have to first use an UDF to convert the Vector in this question into ArrayType.

For spark 2.4+ use udf+sort_array+slice which can use Java's optimization engine to sort but no partial sorting:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, sort_array, slice

udf_extract_1 = udf(lambda v: v.toArray().tolist(), 'array<double>')

(my_model.summary.predictions
    .select('prediction', udf_extract_1('probability').alias('probability'))
    .withColumn('probability', slice(sort_array('probability', False),1,N))
    .show(truncate=False))
```

Or use udf + Python's partial-sorting function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from numpy import partition, arange

udf_extract_2 = udf(lambda v: (-partition(-v.toArray(), arange(N))[:N]).tolist(), 'array<double>')

(my_model.summary.predictions
    .select('prediction', udf_extract_2('probability').alias('probability'))
    .show(truncate=False))
```

Comment: Can you suggest any other method other than rdd map. Because for a distributed environment rdd takes more time.

Comment: you can use dataframe API functions, but need udf to convert datatype first, and the function sort_array using java engine will not be able to do partial sorting. it's questionable if this is a better way. probably just use udf + Python's partial sorting, you will have to test it from your end.